# Click toggle on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I'm building a site with references. Each reference is an element, upon which hovered should reveal a content element containing text. I have a problem with the click() function and mobile devices. More specifically, toggle.

So here's the layout:

[image]

When hovering or clicking (mobile) to an element it should act as followed:

[image]

Here's the HTML structure:

```
       <div class="work" style="background-image: url(<?=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($tyo->ID) )?>)">
            <div class="work-description">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3 class="work-title"><?=$tyo->post_title?></h3>
                    <p class="work-content"><?=$tyo->post_content?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS (short):

```
.work-description {
    opacity: 0;
}

.work:hover .work-description {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

And this works fine. Hovering. I've also put up some jQuery in cases of mobile devices which dont have hovers, so when clicked on parent it should toggle a visible class to the child. Problem is, this is behaving very strangely.

JS:

```
 $('.work').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.work-description').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

When clicking on the elements on a desktop, it works fine. The class toggles on the right element and it switches on and off. But when doing this on a mobile device like iPad, Galaxy Tab, Android phone, **the first click works, but the second (toggling off) doesnt. When clicking on another element, it changes the first element off, then toggles on the second.** Is there something different about mobile devices handling this?

Comment: Can include `css` for `visible` `class` ?

Comment: in mobile you don't have hover

Comment: .work-description.visible { opacity: 1.0; }

Comment: Ofcourse my mobile doesnt have hover. I said that in the post. That's why I am creating a click toggle.